# Sudden ssh connection loss on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, reboot, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Periodically the ssh connection with amazon linux gets stuck and I can not connect anymore. Having to restart the instance ec2 for the connection to return to normal.
This is not an idle connection. After dropping the connection I can not connect again without the instance being restarted.

```
ssh -vvv
```

[image]

date after connection closed
[image]

Comment: You say the connection is 'not idle' i.e. you're doing something on it - what are you doing when it disconnects. Run ssh with -v (more -vvvv's can make it more verbose) to see what's happening and update the question with logs.

Comment: Regardless of whether the connection falls by idle or by my manual disconnection. For a while I can reconnect normally until suddenly I can not anymore. When I restart the instance the connection returns to normal.

Comment: same problem. Is there a log somewhere I can read? Last htop shows memory 900MB/2GB and cpu usage around 2% when it dropped, but aws ec2 monitoring shows 45% cpu utilization, huh

Answer (score 1):

Check out your CPU and Memory usage in the server by using
Free -g command and top command.
If you are running any application that takes more space and CPU power then you need to take some high configured instance type from AWS.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is even related to the hardware size and limits of the instance. But I have already increased the instance and the problem continues to occur.